# How to use CSS text-align property in Vaadin Flow?

Tags: java, css, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I started to learn Vaadin Flow not long ago (I know "core" Java) and I had a problem. I saw on the Vaadin  documentation that to style our web page, one must go into "frontend/themes/projectName/styles.css", in my case "frontend/themes/my-todo/styles.css".

I tried to change the background ccolor of a Div element, it worked. I also changed the font of my text, and it worked. But when I wanted to use CSS' "text-align: center" it didn't work.

My code:

MainView.java

```java
package com.example.application.views.main;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Div;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.H1;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;

public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

    public MainView() {
        VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        Div appHeader = new Div();
        H1 h1 = new H1("Test");
        appHeader.add(h1);
        appHeader.addClassName("app-header");
        add(appHeader);
    }

}
```

styles.css

```css
html {
    text-align: center;
}

.app-header {
    font-family: "Inter";
    color: red;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are applying the `text-align` CSS property correctly. You don't state how you want the UI to look in your question (hint: it helps you get better answers if you tell what you want to achieve), but I assume you want the appHeader Div centered on the screen. [What the `text-align` property does according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align):

> The text-align CSS property sets the horizontal alignment of the inline-level content inside a block element or table-cell box.

What you have in your MainView is *not* inline-level content inside a block element (or a table-cell box). You have a column-direction flex container (vaadin-vertical-layout), which contains a block element (div), which contains another block element (h1). So instead, you want to center a block element horizontally inside a column flex container. Here's what you can do with your existing structure and only one change to your CSS:

```
.app-header {
    font-family: "Inter";
    color: red;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```